# How can I align two boxes to the top right and top left of a surrounding box?

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes, subscripts, superscripts

Assuming the following structure (auto-generated from another document), how should I define `\csup` and `\csub` to line the `sup` boxes to line up with the top of the neighbouring box, and the `sub` boxes to line up with the bottom?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\csup}[1]{\scriptsize{#1}}
\newcommand*{\csub}[1]{\scriptsize{#1}}
\newcommand*{\cnotation}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\crepeat}[1]{\fbox{#1}}
\newcommand*{\cwrapper}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\cwrapper{\crepeat{%
    AAA
    \cwrapper{\crepeat{%
        BBB
        \cwrapper{\crepeat{CCC}\csup{pC}\csub{bC}}}
      \csup{pB}\csub{bB}}}
  \csup{pA}\csub{bA}}
\end{document}
```

In other words, how do I change the document to produce this:

[image: desired result]

instead of this?

[image: current result]

I tried raisebox and adjustbox, but the following is the best I could get:

```
\newcommand*{\csup}[1]{\adjustbox{valign=t}{\scriptsize{\rlap{#1}}}}
\newcommand*{\csub}[1]{\adjustbox{valign=b}{\scriptsize{#1}}}
```

[image: failed-attempt]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(simplified the answer to show both candidate solution methods in one go)

Here are two candidate solutions. The first positions the sub- and superscript terms relative to the right-hand edge of the immediately preceding box, while the second ignores the height of the immediately preceding box.

The main changes, relative to your code, are (a) making `\cwrapper` take three arguments (#1: the material to be placed in a box; #2 and #3: the superscript and subscript terms) and (b) using math mode to help position the super- and subscript terms relative to the preceding material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\cscr}[1]{\textnormal{\scriptsize #1}}
\newcommand*{\cwrappera}[3]{%
    $\left.{\textnormal{\fbox{#1}}}\ \right.^{\cscr{#2}}_{\cscr{#3}}$}
\newcommand*{\cwrapperb}[3]{%
    \fbox{#1} ${\vphantom{\textnormal{#1}}}^{\cscr{#2}}_{\cscr{#3}}$}

\begin{document}
\cwrappera{AAA
    \cwrappera{BBB
        \cwrappera{CCC}{pC}{bC}}
        {pB}{bB}}
    {pA}{bA} 

\medskip
\cwrapperb{AAA
    \cwrapperb{BBB
        \cwrapperb{CCC}{pC}{bC}}
        {pB}{bB}}
    {pA}{bA}        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! So there's no way around wrapping everything in math?

Comment: @Clément - One has to make the subscript and superscript terms aware of the vertical dimensions of the preceding rectangular box, right? Encasing the box in a `\left. ... \right.` "wrapper" achieves this objective. There may well be other methods.

Comment: @Clément - I've updated my answer to provide an additional solution method and to display the output of the two solution methods in one and the same screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Mico. Your first solution works really nicely, and it actually doesn't require changing the signature of my command (which is great, because the LaTeX is auto-generated by Sphinx). However, the math aspect breaks hyperref; no idea why. I've open [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310877/why-does-usepackageamsmath-break-hyperref-in-textnormal) about that.

Answer (score 4):

The original syntax of the OP can be preserved with this formulation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\csub}[1]{_\textnormal{~#1}}
\newcommand*{\csup}[1]{^\textnormal{~#1}}
\newcommand*{\cnotation}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\crepeat}[1]{\fbox{#1}}
\newcommand*{\cwrapper}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
\begin{document}
\cwrapper{\crepeat{%
    AAA
    \cwrapper{\crepeat{%
        BBB
        \cwrapper{\crepeat{CCC}\csup{pC}\csub{bC}}}
      \csup{pB}\csub{bB}}}
  \csup{pA}\csub{bA}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I use `\cwrapper` to ensure math mode, and then use `\csub` and `\csup` to employ math sub and superscripts with `\text` macros.

---

If one wants the sub- and superscripts tighter, then this would do, where I have moved the subscript up 1pt and the superscript down 2.5pt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\csub}[1]{_\textnormal{~#1}}
\newcommand*{\csup}[1]{^\textnormal{~#1}}
\newcommand*{\cnotation}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\crepeat}[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{\fbox{#1}}\ht0=\dimexpr\ht0-2.5pt\relax%
  \dp0=\dimexpr\dp0-1pt\relax\box0}
\newcommand*{\cwrapper}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
\begin{document}
\cwrapper{\crepeat{%
    AAA
    \cwrapper{\crepeat{%
        BBB
        \cwrapper{\crepeat{CCC}\csup{pC}\csub{bC}}}
      \csup{pB}\csub{bB}}}
  \csup{pA}\csub{bA}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neat, +1; that's exactly what I was referring to in my comment to Mico.

Comment: Are `_` and `^` reversed in the definitions of `\csub` and `\csup`? Separately, for extra stability -- and to improve the chances of getting @egreg's stamp of approval :-) -- one might also replace `^\text{~#1}` with `^{\textnormal{~#1}}`, etc.

Comment: @Clément That's not the alginment you asked for is it? It doesn't match what's shown in your target image. (I matched the target although the question leaves the handling of a subscript with a descender ambiguous.)

Comment: @cfr: Looks fine to me :) What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @Clément I meant in the first one, I think.

Comment: May I ask, why did you use tilda before #1? Another thing - is cwrapper command good for anything in original code (now it has ensuremath but before there...I couldn't see why it was needed)?... also is there a topic about doing that setbox and that changing of dimensions? It looks useful and I would like to learn it...

Comment: @JozefJanočko The tilde is a hard space, between the box and the sub/superscripts, which your original figure seemed to support.  Since this solution must be performed in math mode, the use of `\encuremath` in `\cwrapper`  makes sure that it is, regardless of whether you invoke the macros in text mode or math mode.  To some extent, the use of multiple `\cwrapper` macros is redundant (only the outer one is needed); however, you had indicated the syntax was auto-generated from another document, so I left it fully intact...

Comment: @JozefJanočko I learned the trick of changing a box dimension from one of David Carlisle's answers here at the site, rather than from a book.  First, one should master the concept of temporary boxes such as `\box0` (pp. 120-122 The Texbook).  LaTeX has a syntax for permanent boxes such as `\newsavebox{\toy}\savebox{\toy}[.65in]{gnats}` (pp.96-101 LaTeX User Guide & Reference Manual)).  `\ht` and `\dp` are measures of height and depth of a box above and below the baseline, respectively, while `\wd` is a measure of box width...

Comment: @JozefJanočko For temporary boxes, `\dp0=<length>` is a way of changing the box depth, prior to printing the box with `\box0`.  For permanent boxes, `\dp\toy=<length>` is the comparable technique, prior to printing the box with `\usebox{\toy}`.

Comment: Thanx a lot :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version respecting the clumsy syntax you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cwrapper}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\check@mathfonts
  \begingroup\ignorespaces
  #1%
  \clement@wrap
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\crepeat}[1]{%
  \def\clement@repeat{#1}\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\csup}[1]{\def\clement@sup{#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\csub}[1]{\def\clement@sub{#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\clement@wrap}{%
  \sbox\z@{\fbox{\clement@repeat}}%
  \copy\z@
  \raisebox{-\dp\z@}{%
    \vbox to \dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@{
      \hrule height\z@
      \hbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont\clement@sup}
      \vss
      \hbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont\clement@sub}
      \hrule height\z@
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cwrapper{\crepeat{AAA}\csup{a}\csub{b}}

\cwrapper{\crepeat{%
    AAA
    \cwrapper{\crepeat{%
        BBB
        \cwrapper{\crepeat{CCC}\csup{pC}\csub{bC}}}
      \csup{pB}\csub{bB}}}
  \csup{pA}\csub{bA}}

\Large
\cwrapper{\crepeat{AAA}\csup{a}\csub{b}}

\end{document}
```

Note that also font size changes are respected.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just because it is there, here's a version which uses coffins to arrange and typeset the boxes.

The syntax is identical to that specified in the question except that `\cwrapper` can take an optional argument specifying the horizontal distance between the larger box and the superscript and subscripts. Since this is optional, the OP's syntax can be used unchanged. In that case, the default is `1pt`, but this can obviously be modified as desired.

Essentially, each of `\csup`, `\csub` and `\crepeat` is defined to put its content into a coffin. `\cwrapper` is defined to join the coffins appropriately and typeset the result. Nesting works as expected, as shown in the extended example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_clement_main_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_clement_tmpa_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_clement_sup_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_clement_sub_coffin
\dim_new:N \l_clement_spacer_dim
\NewDocumentCommand \csup { m }
{
  \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_clement_sup_coffin { \scriptsize #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \csub { m }
{
  \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_clement_sub_coffin { \scriptsize #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \crepeat { m }
{
  \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_clement_tmpa_coffin { \fbox { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } } }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \cwrapper { O { 1pt } m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \clement_cwrapper:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn { NnnNnnVn }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \clement_cwrapper:nn #1 #2
{
  #2
  \dim_set:Nn \l_clement_spacer_dim { #1 }
  \coffin_join:NnnNnnVn \l_clement_tmpa_coffin { r } { t } \l_clement_sup_coffin { l } { t } \l_clement_spacer_dim { 0pt }
  \coffin_join:NnnNnnVn \l_clement_tmpa_coffin { \l_clement_tmpa_coffin-r } { \l_clement_tmpa_coffin-b } \l_clement_sub_coffin { l } { b } \l_clement_spacer_dim { 0pt }
  \coffin_set_eq:NN \l_clement_main_coffin \l_clement_tmpa_coffin
  \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_clement_main_coffin { l } { H } { 0pt } { 0pt }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\cwrapper{\crepeat{%
    AAA
  }%
  \csup{pA}\csub{bA}%
}

\cwrapper{\crepeat{%
    AAA
    \cwrapper{\crepeat{%
        BBB
      }%
      \csup{pB}\csub{bB}%
    }%
  }%
  \csup{pA}\csub{bA}%
}

\cwrapper{\crepeat{%
    AAA
    \cwrapper{\crepeat{%
        BBB
        \cwrapper{\crepeat{CCC}\csup{pC}\csub{bC}%
        }%
      }%
      \csup{pB}\csub{bB}%
    }%
  }%
  \csup{pA}\csub{bA}%
}

\cwrapper[5pt]{\crepeat{%
    AAA
    \cwrapper{\crepeat{%
        BBB
        \cwrapper[10pt]{\crepeat{CCC}\csup{pC}\csub{bC}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \csup{pA}\csub{bA}%
}

\cwrapper{\crepeat{%
    AAA
    \cwrapper{\crepeat{%
        BBB
        \cwrapper{\crepeat{CCC}\csup{pC}%
        }%
      }%
      \csub{bB}%
    }%
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: coffin series]

Comment: Bonus point for naming something `clement_main_coffin` :) But that doesn't really match what I was looking for: the baselines of AAA, BBB, and CCC are not aligned in your example.

Comment: @Clément Ah. You're right - I missed that. I'll take a look later. (About to leave here now as need to catch a bus.)

Comment: @Clément Please see edit. I think you just wanted to pick a different pole? Is `H` right?

Comment: Brilliant, spot on. I had never hear of TeX coffins before.

Comment: @Clément I've been playing with them and they are kind of cool. I'm quite impressed they do so well nested like this. Take a look at the documentation for `xcoffins` - kind of neat, though I find they take some getting used to ;).