# Why does \usepackage{amsmath} break \hyperref in \textnormal?

Tags: xetex, hyperref, amsmath

In the following sample, the second link isn't hyperlinked:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % Removing this makes the second link work
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \hyperref[abc-def]{link} % This link works
  \(\textnormal{\hyperref[abc-def]{link}}\) % But not this one
  \label{abc-def} Target
\end{document}
```

However, removing `\usepackage{amsmath}` fixes the second link. Why is that? And how can I make the second link work without removing amsmath?

(This is a simplified example from auto-generated XeLaTeX sources, so modifying the code itself is rather inconvenient).

Here is a slightly larger example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\hyperref[lbl]{term}
\(\textnormal{\hyperref[lbl]{term}}\)

\newpage
\subsubsection{Abc}
\phantomsection\label{lbl} def
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: if I change `\label{abc-def}Target` into `\newpage Text\phantomsection\label{abc-def}Target` both links point to the intended destination.

Comment: @egreg Maybe I oversimplified the example then. What I mean is that is that `hyperref` behaves differently inside of a math block, but only when amsmath is loaded.

Comment: @Clément `\text...` commands are completely different if amsmath is loaded (they are a mathchoice so set at 4 different sizes internally so they work in subscripts)

Comment: @egreg I can't reproduce your result; I've added a larger example that still shows the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the explanation; do you know of a way to make hypertext work in that setting, though? Maybe by saving a copy of the unmodified `\text` before loading amsmath?

Comment: it appears to be a problem with the xelatex back end (it works with pdflatex) I can look (I seem to have aquired write access to both amsmath and hyperref in recent months....)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle brilliant, thanks very much!

Comment: This works with pdftex and luatex fails with xetex and latex(dvipdfm option) and dvipdfmx driver

Comment: can you raise an issue at https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues (I could, but if you do it, you'll get notified if anything gets fixed)

Comment: @Clément I didn't use XeLaTeX, that's why!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** Fixed in Hyperref  v6.83p

---

It appears that the macro code for xetex/dvipdfm(x) only inserts the link in the first choice of a mathchoice (so it works in displaystyle only)

You could use `\mbox` or a similar construct that forces text size so avoids the mathchoice internally or a possibly better fix is

[image]

here I disabled `amstext` package `\iffirstchoice@` test so the macros can not tell that they are being executed four times. this is what you want when adding a hyperref special but it does mean that if you increment a counter, or make an index entry within `\textnormal` you will get 4 increments or index entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\iffirstchoice@\iftrue
\let\firstchoice@false\relax
\makeatletter

\hyperref[lbl]{1term}
\(\textnormal{\hyperref[lbl]{2term}} x^{\textnormal{\hyperref[lbl]{3term}}}\)

\newpage
\subsubsection{Abc}
\phantomsection\label{lbl} def
\end{document}
```

Comment: possible fix posted to https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues/13